# Create FullCalendar Event By Selecting Date or Time Span

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I need to allow the user to select a date/time span to create a new event.  I have the code that opens the new event when clicking on a day and I can get the date and time selected, but it returns only the start date and time. I don't know how to allow the user to select more than one time/date span, or how to capture the end date/time.

Inside my fullCalendar definition, I have:

```
    dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                var startDate = date._d.toISOString();
                var dueDate = date._d.toISOString();
                startDate = (startDate.substr(5,2)-1)+'/'+startDate.substr(8,2)+'/'+startDate.substr(0,4)+' '+parseInt(startDate.substr(11,2))+':'+startDate.substr(14,2);
                dueDate = (dueDate.substr(5,2)-1)+'/'+dueDate.substr(8,2)+'/'+dueDate.substr(0,4)+' '+(parseInt(dueDate.substr(11,2))+1)+':'+dueDate.substr(14,2);

                //using alert() in place of my function call 
                //to open the actual event creation page
                alert(startDate+'\n'+endDate);
    },
```

Any ideas of how to allow a multi date/time span and then how to capture the end date/time?

Comment: [select](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_method/) may be what you're after instead of dayClick

Comment: That's it @smcd.  I also had to set `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({selectable: true,selectHelper: true, ...})` Thanks for your help.